# Why do I get an exception while trying to connect to Zabbix server using java api

Tags: java, exception, zabbix

I am trying to connect to Zabbix server using this [API](https://github.com/hengyunabc/zabbix-api). With user, password credentials I am able to get access via the web browser. Here is my code

```
public class Main {
public static DefaultZabbixApi zabbixApi;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String url = "http://zabbixServer/zabbix/api_jsonrpc.php";
    String user = "user";
    String password = "password";

    try {
        zabbixApi = new DefaultZabbixApi(url);
        zabbixApi.init();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    boolean login = zabbixApi.login(user,password); //line 28

    System.out.println(zabbixApi.apiVersion());
}
```

But receive this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONException: syntax error, pos 1
    at com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.DefaultJSONParser.parse(DefaultJSONParser.java:1248)
    at com.alibaba.fastjson.parser.DefaultJSONParser.parse(DefaultJSONParser.java:1158)
    at com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON.parse(JSON.java:141)
    at com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON.parse(JSON.java:125)
    at com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON.parse(JSON.java:112)
    at io.github.hengyunabc.zabbix.api.DefaultZabbixApi.call(DefaultZabbixApi.java:139)
    at io.github.hengyunabc.zabbix.api.DefaultZabbixApi.login(DefaultZabbixApi.java:76)
    at Main.main(Main.java:28)
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Looks like it's not returning a json object. Probably you must add some query parameters to retrieve things from the URL specified.

Comment: The github project wasn't updated in the last 3 years and is based on the 2.4 API. It's specified that it will yeald an exception with 2.2 version, maybe it doesn't work with newer API as well. There's a fork for 3.x here: https://github.com/adamitj/zabbix3-api